# apache cxf webservice : tomcat is showing requested resource not found while server is up for <soap:address>

Tags: xml, web-services, tomcat, soap, wsdl

I am using CXF for webservices. All is working fine till i am generating wsdl file. but when i am trying to access this link which is defined in .wsdl file's  tag tomcat is showing

"HTTP Status 404 - /MyFirstWebService/SubtractionImplPort

type Status report

message /MyFirstWebService/SubtractionImplPort

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47" 
error.

this is a part of my wsdl file.

```
     <wsdl:service name="SubtractionImplService">
 <wsdl:port name="SubtractionImplPort" binding="tns:SubtractionImplServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address  location="http://localhost:8080/MyFirstWebService/services/SubtractionImplPort"/>
     </wsdl:port>
     </wsdl:service>
```

Please help me in resolving this issue. Any effort would be appreciated...

Comment: Please somebody resolve this issue.. suggest anything...

Answer (score 0):

I tried one webservice demo using JAX-WS,
(http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-attachment-with-mtom/)
Please cross check in your implementation.
Have you published this url in your implementation?

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/MyFirstWebService/services/SubtractionImplPort", new SubtractionImpl());
```

Please explain your implemenation little bit, It seems you have missed something in your client implementation.
Thanks,
ambuj

Comment: I tried your suggestion but this is not working...
         <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" address="127.0.0.1"
 protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

I edited server.xml of my tomcat server.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Use your system IP. Go to cmd->type ipconfig -all, copy ipv4 address from here. Replace localhost with this ip. Hope it would work.

Comment: i used this
http://192.168.1.102:8080/MyFirstWebService/services/SubtractionImplPort



or 

http://192.168.1.102:8080/MyFirstWebService/services/SubtractionImplPort?wsdl

... but still not resolved...

Comment: lets start fresh, type [http://localhost:8080] in web browser and let me know what are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck your web.xml and cxf-beans.xml.

if your URL is http://localhost:8080/MyFirstWebService/services/SubtractionImplPort

/services/* must be the url-pattern in web.xml and

/SubtractionImplPort must be the address in cxf-beans.xml